# show div on top of background overlay

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS code for a background which is acting as an overlay on top of my HTML content:

```
#ticket{
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }

    #ticket:before {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        background:rgba(137,137,137,0.7);
        content: "";
        top:0;
        left:0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index:9999;
    }
```

How can i make the div JQueryPopup div show on top of the overlay?

https://jsfiddle.net/gun82rgy/1/

Comment: Can't you just lower the `z-index`? - https://jsfiddle.net/gun82rgy/5/

Answer (score 1):

Just set a above value in z-index. The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

```
.JQueryPopup {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top:25%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 600px;
    min-height: 80px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #F36F25;
    z-index: 99999; //See here
    box-shadow: #000000 0 2px 18px;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/gun82rgy/2/)**